# VIPER общение между ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, архитектура

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста кто в курсе. 
Как правильно организовать связь между вью контроллером с контейнером и вью контроллером который отображаеться в нем при архитектуре VIPER

Связь должно быть туда и обратно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606439/5426587 - как и любое общение между модулями, из presenter-а в presenter, через router(wireframe). Создаете делегатов для общения между модулями. https://github.com/strongself/The-Book-of-VIPER/blob/master/russian/module-transitions.md - мануал по viper от rambler.